# VirtualBox: Increase Storage SATA port size

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive

- see image please.
- I Have UBUNTU DESKTOP installed on the computer, and I have VirtualBox with UBUNTU Server.
- When I created the computer I assigned about 25GB of Hard Disk and I am needing more.
- How do you increase the SATA port hard disk size?
- If there are commands to be ran, will those need to be ran in the Terminal of the GUEST HOST in virtualbox, or in the GNOME Terminal on the Computer?
  [image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are fine with adding another Virtual Hard Disk to the VM, then do this.

- Right click on the VM and go into Settings > Storage
- Inside Storage, Go into Storage Tree and click on the [Hard Disk Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV6wl.png) next to 'Controller : SATA'
- Choose 'Create new disk' and Set the name, File Size and everything else to suit your needs.
- After that is done, Click on 'Create' and then boot into the VM.
- The disk you just created will be treated as an additional mount, so you will have to configure the space accordingly.

This is my first answer, I hope it helps. Please do ignore it if you already knew about this and chose not to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I have linked to a possible duplicate question above but for your specific example you could try the following on the Host computer:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd seerverubuntu.vdi --resize 30000
```

which would make it approximately 30GB. Note that the new size must be in MB, there is a nice converter here:

[Convert GB to MB - Conversion of Measurement Units](http://www.convertunits.com/from/GB/to/MB)

You then have 2 options:

1. To simply create a new partition you will have to install `gparted`from *within* the guest VM:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   ```

   Open `gparted` within the VM and then create a new partition with the unallocated space.
2. But to absorb the 'unallocated' space into an existing partition you will need to attach either of the following to your VM (Under Settings --> Storage --> Storage Tree):

   - An Ubuntu LiveCD iso
   - The GParted Live CD

   Then boot the VM and select the option 'Live CD' and then absorb the unallocated space into an existing partition.

**Note:** Before working with `gparted` it would be an excellent idea to back up all of the important data from the VM...